# Why is the smart icon purple?

Tags: icons

I was looking for an icon to represent a "smart folder" and when I did a search on Google, most of the icons came up as:

- A folder icon (may or may not be purple)
- Plus a "gear" icon (may or may not be purple)

My question is why purple? Is this standard?

Comment: I have no idea, I assume this is a branding thing from some company. I don't know of any particular reason for it...

Comment: Perhaps because, at least to the best of my knowledge, purple is a color that is not yet identifiable with anything symbolic just yet? Yellow is caution, red is a warning, green is complete/save, etc.

Comment: color is rarely useful as a universal part of iconography given the range of cultures, screens, and levels of color blindness.

Comment: Red is perhaps identified with warning and green with safety (in UX including in traffic lights) due to the fact red symbolizes fire and green symbolizes natural green fields. There are non-UX symbolic meanings for most colors. These meanings are of course culture dependant, however, UX usually uses Western culture's conventions.

Comment: @BenBrocka Is this one of the questions referred to [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137870/grey-fade-out-closed-questions-like-questions-with-ignored-tags) as saveable? (I think I saw you commented on that meta question too - did you delete your comment?)

Comment: @DannyVarod I don't really think so..."Why was this done?" "Because that's how Apple did it" doesn't really help. I guess "How should Smart folders be represented in OSX" is marginally more helpful, if obvious...

Comment: @BenBrocka I think there is some logic behind associating purple with the term "smart" whether or not Apple did it first. Why do Apple call them "smart folders" instead of "search folders"?

Comment: @DannyVarod some color stuff is very interesting, some is very suspect. Purple is certainly a color of royalty in Western cultures, but to say a color of good judgement seems highly suspect...especially from a site about Chakras

Comment: @BenBrocka There is a reason I put that quote last :-) I'll edit out that part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

['Smart Folders'](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.4/en/mh2152.html) are a proprietary thing in OSX. Their icon is purple:

[image: http://www.trickyways.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/smart-folder-with-changed-name.png]

Answer (score 2):

The color Purple has a few meanings (that I know of):

- A balance between hot (red) and cold (blue)
- Purple is a deep and less common color which is identified with mystery

A quick search also returns these results:

> Purple is warm and cool. Explore its meaning and symbolism, colors that go with purple and the light and dark shades from palest orchid to deep dark violet and indigo.
>
> Shades of Purple: These words are synonymous with or represent various shades of the color purple: amethyst, eggplant, indigo, lavender, lilac, magenta (see fuchsia), mauve, mulberry, orchid, plum, pomegranate, puce, royal, thistle, violet, wine.
>
> Nature and Culture:
>
> Purple is royalty. A mysterious color, it is associated with both nobility and spirituality. The opposites of hot red and cool blue combine to create this intriguing color.

Source: http://desktoppub.about.com/cs/colorselection/p/purple.htm

> Meaning of the Color Purple
>
> Purple embodies the balance of red simulation and blue calm. This dichotomy can cause unrest or uneasiness unless the undertone is clearly defined at which point the purple takes on the characteristics of its undertone. A sense of mystic and royal qualities, purple is a color often well liked by very creative or eccentric types and is the favorite color of adolescent girls.
>
> How the color purple affects us mentally and physically
>   * Uplifting
>   * Calming to mind and nerves
>   * Offers a sense of spirituality
>   * Encourages creativity

Source: http://www.squidoo.com/colorexpert#module1541679

> Purple has been used to symbolize magic and mystery, as well as royalty. Being the combination of red and blue, the warmest and coolest colors, purple is believed to be the ideal color. Most children love the color purple. Purple is the color most favored by artists.

Source: http://crystal-cure.com/purple.html